# Argument cannot be null : findtext ; Need Some advice

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I got stuck on

> Argument Cannot be null :findtext

but I am quite sure that variable already pass into function

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return render('Login', { message: '' });
}

function doPost(e) {
  /////////////// Page Login ////////////////////////
  if (e.parameter.LoginButton == 'Login') {
    var usercode = e.parameter.usercode;
    var password = e.parameter.password;
    var username = checkLogin(usercode, password);
    if (username != 'FALSE') {
      ////// Login สำเร็จ
      var r = GetRound();
      var a = GetArray(usercode);
      return render('Table', { array: a, round: r, time: t });
    }
  }//added by editor
}//added by editor

function GetTimeTable(Usercode) {
  var lastrow = PayrollSheet.getLastRow();
  var testdata = ScanSheet.getRange(5, 2, lastrow, 5);
  var Row = testdata.createTextFinder(Usercode).findNext().getRow(); /// Error Here
  var Array = ScanSheet.getRange(Row, 2, 5, 18).getDisplayValues();
  return Array;
}

function GetArray(Usercode) {
  var lastrow = PayrollSheet.getLastRow();
  var testdata = PayrollSheet.getRange(4, 1, lastrow, 18);
  var Row = testdata
    .createTextFinder(Usercode)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findNext()
    .getRow();
  var Array = PayrollSheet.getRange(Row, 1, 1, 18).getValues().flat();
  return Array;
}
```

**Javascript in html**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){    
var loginuser = document.getElementById("loginuser").value ;  //Get Usercode from  Html param
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).GetTimeTable(loginuser) ;    
});
```

I really have no idea what happen ,It work really fine when I call GetArray() but I call from Google script side.

Comment: Where is `findtext`, I don't see it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. It's missing two  braces `}`

Comment: Log `loginuser` client side and add the logs in your question.

Comment: TheWizEd - Im not sure about that too but I think it came from method createTextFinder.                         TheMaster - mayby missing when copied but code can run without syntax error